# Wifi being very slow/not working for linux on Mac; Why won't it connect?

Tags: networking, wifi, macos

When using a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 on a Macbook 15" 2015 model, wifi connections are not working - The wifi networks show up but do not connect (VERY occasionally they do but only work temporarily before cutting out again).

My network card & driver info

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
> 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac
  Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 02)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [106b:0173]
  Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
```

My OS info

```
$ uname -a
> Linux dylan-MacBookPro 5.3.0-40-generic #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 14:05:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: i have slow on Macbook 12 BCM4350 [14e4:43a3] (rev 05) 5Ghz slower 2.4Ghz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2015 apple mac laptops use a `Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602` network card. The reason it won't work on linux is because the Broadcom drivers would require a firmware update and the process for doing that is apparently quite time consuming and expensive - simply put; Fixing this issue is not worth Broadcom's time.

**Despite this, a manual fix is possible by making a couple of changes to the brcm config file.**

As a prerequisite, in case you have already tried to fix this issue and installed other drivers etc. run this;

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt update
sudo update-pciids
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo reboot
```

Then download the configuration file;

```
sudo cd /lib/firmware/brcm/
sudo wget -O brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=285753
```

Copy the mac address of your network card (you will need this in a minute) - it should look something like `00:90:4c:0d:f4:3e`;

```
ip addr | grep ether
```

Then change the bcrm43602 configuration by editing this file;

```
sudo nano brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt
```

Navigate to these parameters and change them;

```
macaddr=<paste your network card's mac address>
ccode=0
regrev=0
```

Then;

```
sudo reboot
```

Credit to the users in this thread here; https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193121

For some reason, the wifi networks are shown but they do not have any bars - Not to worry! They still work. Simply click and try to connect.

Answer (score 0):

wow after all the search this seems to have helped, like magic, none of the other steps were sufficient without the
Then download the configuration file;

sudo cd /lib/firmware/brcm/
sudo wget -O brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=285753

Copy the mac address of your network card (you will need this in a minute) - it should look something like 00:90:4c:0d:f4:3e;

ip addr | grep ether

Then change the bcrm43602 configuration by editing this file;

sudo nano brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt

Navigate to these parameters and change them;

macaddr=<paste your network card's mac address>
ccode=0
regrev=0

I am almost afraid to reboot in case it does not work!
This was so frustrating

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that your first sentence seems to be incomplete. You may want to revise your post - at that occasion, please use the [formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) tools to make your text easier to read (in particular, use code formatting for verbatim code and keyword reprodution).